# Please help me to understand the Taylor’s theorem when transiting from Gradient Boost to XGboost

Tags: boosting, gradient-descent, derivative, hessian, taylor-series

I am reading [this article](https://medium.com/@matthias.burbach/xgboost-uses-taylor-ecdf961751ff), which explains how the algorithm replaces the actual loss function with so-called 2nd order Taylor expansion. I can understand til Step 4, and can't understand step 5.

I understand this, this is from step 4:
[image]

But when it is going to step 5, I can't understand it:
[image]

Where does the 2 under the ''(a) come from? or How does the substitution/transformation happen?

Comment: the integral of x  dx between a and b  is  b^2/2 - a^2/2